# How to get background of itemview in android

Tags: android, background

My code is used to show schedule from database to `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`. When user click into item, this item will change background, and when user click into item again, this item will change to default background.
So my question is how to get background of itemview? and how to compare with `R.color.colorPrimaryDark`.
Here is my code

```
mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Schedule, ScheduleViewHolder>(Schedule.class, R.layout.item_schedule,
                ScheduleViewHolder.class, query) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final ScheduleViewHolder viewHolder, Schedule model, final int position) {
                final DatabaseReference scheduleRef = getRef(position);
                // Set click listener for the whole post view
                final String scheduleKey = scheduleRef.getKey();
                Log.d("ScheduleKey", scheduleKey);

                viewHolder.bindToSchedule(model);
                viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        viewHolder.itemView.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
                        viewHolder.txtName.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                        viewHolder.txtNumber.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                        viewHolder.txtAddress.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                        viewHolder.txtIconOri.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                        viewHolder.txtIconHere.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                    }
                });
            }
        };
```

Comment: your view in adapter is your backgroung like convertview..it will in onbindViewholder.

Comment: In my code, I setted background is R.color.colorPrimaryDark, and I don't know how to check if background current is R.color.colorPrimaryDark

Comment: view.getBackground()

Comment: @ThanhDuy Better make a boolean flag for each item, and change the color accordingly.

Comment: @FAЯAƸ thank you, I solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your solution may be like this:

```
 int color = R.color.colorPrimaryDark;
        Drawable background = view.getBackground();
        if (background instanceof ColorDrawable)
            color = ((ColorDrawable) background).getColor()
```

in color you can get background color.

Comment: you try this or not?

Comment: I tried, but it's not work. I don't know how to add code into comment :D.